# pitch choice for steel drums

Tags: tuning, percussion

When a steel drum is being tuned up are the pitches determined chromatically or are they tuned diatonically to a specific key? I'm asking about Jamaican style steel drums, just to be clear.

Comment: It looks like tuning patterns vary based on the range of the drum (bigger pans I guess have room for more notes). But it looks chromatic to me. https://www.caribbean-steel-drums.com/steel-drums-steel-pan-family.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one I used to play around 40 yrs ago was a soprano pan, basically tuned to key D. It was divided into around two octaves, diatonically. Pretty sure there were no chromatics on it then. There would probably be more resonance without chromatics.